# Write access on volume for CNB Docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am working on a spring boot application that should be migrated into a docker container (used to run as a systemd service on a server)
The app reads and writes a configurable path on the file system - lets for now assume it is `/var/mypath`

I built a docker image using the `bootBuildImage` task from springs gradle plugin. it used what appears to be the default builder image, namely `gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder` to build the application image.

Consequently, in a docker compose file, I defined a stack, with the (unimportant) mysql db and the spring boot app like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend_db:
    container_name: "backend_db"
    image: "mariadb:latest"
    # ...

  backend_app:
    depends_on:
      - "backend_db"
    container_name: "backend_app"
    image: "myImageName:latest"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "app:/var/mypath"
    environment:
      # mysql data etc...

volumes:
  db:
  app:
```

When I start it up with `docker-compose up`, the spring-boot application does not have write access on `/var/mypath`.
I figured out, that apparently the CNB build makes the spring application run as user `cnb`.
I suppose, the volume is created as root and only root has write access to it.

The manual-chown approach seems suboptimal, since I would have expected to be able to just `docker-compose up` on a server and be done, instead of manually chowning around but anyways:
I have tried to `chown` the volume to the cnb user from within the container  without success:

> chown cnb /var/mypath/
> chown: changing ownership of '/var/mypath/': Operation not permitted

How can I make sure, that the spring boot application can write the volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to chown/chgrp the volume after all - my mistake was that it does not work from within the container (there is no sudo) - but it works from outside using docker exec, specifying the root user:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it backend_app chown cnb /var/mypath
docker exec -u 0 -it backend_app chgrp cnb /var/mypath
```

User @Stuck also suggested a more elaborate approach by creating another docker-image layer: [can `bootBuildImage` create writeable volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353768/can-bootbuildimage-create-writeable-volumes)

Andy Wilkinson from Spring pointed out that this is a general Docker issue - so if some other solution pops up in the future, I'm glad to update this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker Compose and you don't want to have to execute manual `chown` commands before deploying, you can also add a service which sets the volume world-writable.

This means you can just run `docker compose up` on a fresh host and have a writeable volume.

```yaml
volumes:
  logs:

services:
  volume-initializer:
    image: alpine
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "chmod 777 /volume"
    volumes:
      - logs:/volume

  my_app:
    depends_on: [volume-initializer]
    volumes:
      - logs:/logs
    ...
```